# SharePoint 2013 Formula Syntax: Choice Column Generates Number in Another Column

Tags: list, calculated-column, syntax

I am trying to make the following happen on a list: If a user selects "Most" as a choice, then another column will return as 1. If a user selects "Somewhat" then that column will return a .5. If a user selects "None" then that column will return a .0. Any advice on the formula syntax?

Answer (score 1):

In a calculated column,

```
IF([ColumnA]="Most","1",IF([ColumnA]="Somewhat",".5",IF([ColumnA]="None","0",NULL)))
```

`[ColumnA]` should be changed to the name of your column.
`NULL` can be changed to a default value if nothing is selected.